# Problem with some sensors but not with servos

Tags: sensors, hardware, ultrasonics

I use a lot Arduino Uno, but in this case, I have some [BQ ZUM BT-328 boards](https://www.electronicsdatasheets.com/manufacturers/bq/parts/zum-bt328), which are based on Arduino BT. The problem with some of BQ ZUM BT-328 boards is that the ultrasonic sensor ([HC-SR04](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/1132203/ETC2/HC-SR04.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw6cKiBhD5ARIsAKXUdyZcI10wW6rgVh6BaDVhlH8hpniDbfgKCNIIO77sIs1qq-c9nZZLqMEaAl3IEALw_wcB)) is not working in any pin. However, apparantely, the boards work and the 2 servos ([SM-S4306R](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/897796/SPRINGRC/SM-S4306R/1)) work fine too. When I change the ultrasonic sensor to other pins and with other wires, it is not working yet. However, I use that sensor in another different BQ ZUM BT-328 board and it is working fine, and if I add the same setup (2 SM-S4306R) and same code, it continues working fine. Then, the problem is just in some boards, not in everyone.

The ultrasonic example is:

```
long distance;
long responseTime;

int pinTrig = 9;
int pinEcho = 8;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinTrig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinEcho, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  digitalWrite(pinTrig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  
  digitalWrite(pinTrig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  responseTime = pulseIn(pinEcho, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Tiempo "+ String(responseTime)+" microsegundos");
  
  distance = int(0.01716*responseTime);

  Serial.println("Distancia "+ String(distance)+"cm");
  delay(500);
}
```

Then, I suppose that those BQ ZUM BT-328 boards have some problem and maybe they are starting to fail. I say this, because the same problem works in some boards and in others fails. In those board in which it fails I checked the correct connection of pins (GND, VCC, digitals), change the pin and the wires without result. However, the servos continue to work fine and I can upload the code to the board. My questions are:

Am I correct and they are failing?

Why they are just failing with that sensor and not the SM-S4306R? I mean, maybe some specific component of the board is failing?

Comment: the questions are not answerable because your description lacks detail

Comment: Which more details do you need? I can add more or test more the board. Just tell me.

Comment: include information about the board, the sensors, the connection diagram and minimal program that shows the failure

Comment: I have added a reference to the datasheet of the board, the sensor, and the motor. I have explain better the mistakes, and added the code example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your sample code you did not complete the 10us pulse.

```
  digitalWrite(pinTrig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  
  digitalWrite(pinTrig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(pinTrig, LOW); // you missed this
```

See [example](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried in all boards adding that line, but the result is the same. The boards which was failing continue failing.